# Windows service not logging with Log4Net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I am using Log4Net v1.2.13.0 with .Net 4.5.  It is logging just fine when I run my code as a console application.  However, when I run it as a service I get nothing. The service is running as my login with admin permissions.  When I attach to the process and step through the code in debug mode it is as if nothing in the config file has even been read.  When you check the logger object none of the properties are set true, e.g. Logger.IsDebugEnabled, Logger.IsInfoEnabled etc.

Here is how I am configuring a logger instance and then retrieving the same instance.

```
private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ServiceHostService));
```

I am setting the logging level to ALL.

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: did you call the Log4Net.Configure somewhere?

Comment: Make sure that your service has write access to the the file that Log4net is writing too. It's more than like an security access issue.

Comment: No I did not call Log4Net.Configure anywhere in the code.  I inherited this code from someone else and it has never called that and has worked fine always as a console application but now I am promoting to a service.  I am  writing to a database table and event log but not a file.  Service has admin on the box and login as dbo for the database.

Comment: Does your config have a `root` logger defined?

Comment: Also note that your service will have to run once in an elevated process to create an event source to enable logging to the event log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `LogManager.GetRepository().Configured` returns false, then log4net has not been initialised.

Assuming you have your config in XML, will need either a call to `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(…)` or an assembly attribute like `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(…)]` to load the config. If it's in a separate file from the app.config, make sure that file is copied to the output.

If log4net is configured but all log levels are still disabled, check for configuration issues by looking at the results of `LogManager.GetRepository().ConfigurationMessages.Cast<LogLog>()`.

It may help if you add your config to your question.

Comment: Although the [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)] was in a class library used for the service it was not actually in the project assembly file marked as such for the service.